# Prove Intersection of Two compact sets is compact using open cover?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let A and B be compact subset of R

To show intersection of A and B is compact,

I need to show that for any open cover for intersection has finite subcover.

It is quite straightforward for Union of two compact sets, but how can I start with the intersection casE?

Comment: Given an open cover for the intersection, augment it with the complement of the intersection. Now you have an open cover for the union so you can proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $B$ be compact. Let $U=\{U_\alpha\}$ be an open covering of $A\cap B$. Since we are working in $\mathbb R$, we know that $A$ and $B$ are both closed. Thus, $A\cap B$ is closed, so $U'=U\cup \{\mathbb R\setminus (A\cap B)\}$ is an open cover of $A\cup B$. Now can you use this to construct a finite subcovering of $A\cap B$?

Comment: not quite sure. If U` is open cover of union, then U` is open cover for A and B.

Comment: Then A and B has finite subcover and if we take intersection of those two finite subcovers, then it is finite subcover for interseection of A and B?

Comment: We know that $A\cup B$ is compact, so there is a finite subcover of $A\cup B$. Then we just take $\mathbb R\setminus(A\cap B)$ out of this subcover, we have a finite subcover of $A\cap B$.