# Prove the intersection of infinitely many compact sets is compact by showing it is closed and bounded

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that a previous proof of this question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990512/proof-feedback-proving-infinite-intersections-of-compact-sets-is-compact), but I want to try to show the above statement using the fact that a set is compact if it is both closed and bounded.

---

We know that any intersection of closed sets is closed. So we need to show that any intersection of bounded sets is bounded.

A set is bounded if it is contained in some ball, $B(0, R)$ about $0$ (or equivalently in a ball about any point).

Since each set $S$ is bounded, there exists a ball $B(0,R)$ such that $S\subset B(0,R)$.

Is it sufficient to say that any intersection of these bounded sets is also bounded since the intersection is a subset of each of its sets (which are bounded)?

Therefore, the intersection of infinitely many compact sets is compact since is it closed and bounded.

Comment: compact means closed and bounded **in** $\mathbf R^n,$ according to the Heine-Borel theorem

Comment: Yes, it's that clear (in $\mathbb{R}^n$).  The intersection will live inside one of its terms, but each of its terms is already bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can say the intersection of an arbitrary collection of bounded sets $\{ A_\alpha\}$is a bounded. This is actually quite simple to see. Choose any $ A \in \{ A_\alpha\}$. $\forall x \in \cap\{ A_\alpha\}, x\in A$. By the definition of boundedness, $\forall x \in A, |x| \le M$ for some $M > 0$. So therefore $\forall x \in \cap\{ A_\alpha\}, x < M$.